# How to change Apache Zeppelin's theme?

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, apache-zeppelin

How to customize the feel and look of a notebook in Apache Zeppelin?, Is there a way to install themes in Zeppelin?

Comment: As of Zeppelin 0.8.0+ (SNAPSHOT currently), it supports javascript extensions. You can create your own extension in this way. https://www.npmjs.com/package/zeppelin-toc-spell Originally, spell is created to provide frontend interpreter, but can use in this way as well.

Comment: Sorry, is there a way to do so without switching to 0.8.0(or higher) version?